# Turborepo/Monorepo multiple jest versions

Tags: jestjs, dependencies, package.json, monorepo, turborepo

I've got a turbo repo with two folders, `apps` and `libs`.  Inside `libs` I have several packages.  I'm trying to upgrade the packages in `libs` to a newer version of jest one at a time, but I'm struggling to get a package under libs to run a newer version of jest without affecting all the other packages.  I've tried overrides, resolutions, nohoist, workspaces. Whenever I run `yarn test` I have a script in `package.json` that spits out the jest version, which does seem to be correct when I run it, however I'm getting test failures consistent with not having the same version.

Essentially I need to upgrade jest in package1 so the newer version runs against package1, but I need to leave jest as the older version in package2

```
 - apps
 - libs
   - package1
     - package.json
   - package2
     - package.json
 - package.json
```